# R: expand.grid with dataset having columns of different sizes

Tags: r, excel, csv

When I do the following:

```
AA=c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE")
aa=c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")
Aa=c("Aa", "Bb", "Cc")
expand.grid(AA, aa, Aa)
```

I get the expected 60 combination of results.

However, if I input the same data in excel and save as a csv with 'AA', 'aa', and 'Aa' as respective column headers and run the following:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Mahshoush\\Desktop")
dir()
data=read.csv("LetterTest.csv", h=T)
head(data)
attach(data)
expand.grid(AA, aa, Aa)
detach(data)
```

I end up with 125 possible combinations that include blank spaces. The weird thing is, I could have sworn I got it to work once but I'm not sure how. I'm not sure if it's how I'm saving my csv file through excel or what I should be doing differently.

Comment: It would help if you can include a reproducible example.  In particular, paste the output from `dput(data)` in your question so that we can replicate your problem.

Comment: You may have a bunch of empty cells in your Excel files. Since all data.frame's in R are rectangular, you will have a 3 column, 5 row dataset that gives 5^3 = 125 combinations including a bunch of blanks.

Comment: @HubertL -- thanks for the response, unfortunately same result.

Comment: structure(list(AA = structure(1:5, .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC", 
"DD", "EE"), class = "factor"), aa = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L), .Label = c("", "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"), class = "factor"), 
    Aa = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Aa", 
    "Bb", "Cc"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("AA", "aa", "Aa"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `expand.grid(lapply(data, function(x) x[x != ""]))`.

Comment: @thelatemail -- that seems to be exactly what is happening. Is there a way to not include those blank spaces when using expand.grid?

Comment: @AHandcartAndMohair -- that appears to be exactly what I was looking for. Time to search lapply and see exactly why that works. I'm guessing it looks at "data", and then I'm not sure what function(x) is or does, but it looks to seek out blank spaces. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mahshoush - the point would probably be to not store the data in a rectangular form at all. Or if you absolutely need a csv, make it a 2 column long-form dataset, with 3 groups in one column (AA,aa,Aa), and the values in a separate column.

Comment: To expand (ha) on what @thelatemail said, you would want your data in the form `data <- data.frame(group = c(rep("AA", 5), rep("aa", 4), rep("Aa", 3)), value = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "Aa", "Bb", "Cc"))`.  You can then get your desired result by `expand.grid(split(data$value, data$group))`.